# Convert an object to a JSON string with thrift json serialization

Tags: java, json, thrift, thrift-protocol

I'm new to the thrift. I need to convert my data object to a `JSON string` with `Thrift JSON` serialization.

I tried in this way.

```
TSerializer serializer = new TSerializer(new TSimpleJSONProtocol.Factory());
String json = serializer.toString(object_name);
```

In here is an error, that `object_name` should be in `TBase`. How can I resolve this ?

Comment: You can only serialize object of type struct defined in thrift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In here is an error, that object_name should be in TBase.

Next time, please post the exact error message (use copy+paste), this makes it easier for all of us.

> How can I resolve this?

Whatever you want to serialize with Thrift, must be an descendant of Thrift's `TBase` class. You achieve this by writing some [Thrift IDL](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/idl/) and save it as a file (e.g. `MyDataStructs.thrift`):

```
struct Employee {
    1: string name
    2: string surname
    3: i32 age
}
```

Next, you pass that file to the Thrift compiler and tell him to generate some C# code from it:

```
thrift  -gen csharp  MyDataStructs.thrift
```

This gives you a class derived from TBase:

```
public partial class Employee : TBase
{
  private string _name;
  private string _surname;
  private int _age;

  // properties
  public string Name {... }
  public string Surname  { ... }
  public int Age  { ... }

  // some details omitted

  public void Read (TProtocol iprot)
  {
    // generated code for Read() method
  }

  public void Write(TProtocol oprot) {
    // generated code for Write() method
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    // generated code for ToString() method
  }

}
```

This is what Thrift expects.

Answer (score 3):

If below is what your are doing then it should work. Check if you are doing this. Employee is a demo call here, you have to use your actual class.

```
Employee object_name= new Employee();
object_name.setAge(27);
object_name.setName("Test");

TSerializer serializer = new TSerializer(new TSimpleJSONProtocol.Factory());
String json = serializer.toString(object_name);
```